# eBuildfire: buildfire.userData.search() not working after recent buildfire update

Tags: search, buildfire

I'm having some issues with a custom plugin I created where the method buildfire.userData.search() is no longer working due to an error.

Please note that evertyhing was working ok before the latest Buildfire SDK update. At first the app was no longer working on https://app.buildfire.com/, and then I had the same issue locally after I manually updated the SDK.

I did check the userdata.search documentation and I see this has not changed https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/user-data#search-

Any ideas on what the problem is and how I can fix this?

Error screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqfNo.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following [snippet](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/user-data#search-) runs fine on the latest (1.75.1) on my end. can you run and verify result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        buildfire.userData.search(
  {
    filter: {
      $or: [
        { "$json.rank": { $gt: "600", $lt: "900" } },
        { "$json.name": "Jane Doe" },
      ],
    },
    sort: { rank: 1, lastName: -1 },
    fields: ["rank", "lastName"],
    skip: 20,
    limit: 10,
  },
  "contactInfo",
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.error("there was a problem retrieving your data");

    console.log("Records found: ", result);
  }
);
    </script>
<span>Widget - Hello, world!</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I would check also if there is any redirection happening on the plugin page causing the plugin to lose the instant context.

Comment: Hey there, please review my previous comments I added to the thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a navigation to other pages the easiest thing to do is copy over all querystring you receive on your index.html to the other pages when navigating away from the index page. that should fix all issues.

Comment: There is no query string linked to the index.html page. Also the navigation is handled by the deeplinks and the navigation, what would we need to pass exactly? Would you mind sharing an example with me about how the solution would look?

Comment: The querystring is dynamically passed to the index.html URL when opening the plugin. you can get the querystring using window.location.search. whenever navigating to the new page just append the querystring